# Cannot connect to an Oracle Database through ODBC in UI Path

Tags: database, oracle, odbc, uipath

I am trying to connect to an 11g oracle database in UI Path through ODBC.

I've setup the drivers, the database source and when I test the connection it [succeedes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq3dL.png).
But when I try to run it in UI Path it throws an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPgtn.png). Here is a screenshot of [my connection settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHCkc.png).

My connection string -

"Dsn=BJ_ODBC;uid=user;pwd=pwd;dbq=test;dba=W;apa=T;exc=F;fen=T;qto=T;frc=10;fdl=10;lob=T;rst=T;btd=F;bnf=F;bam=IfAllSuccessful;num=NLS;dpm=F;mts=T;mdi=F;csr=F;fwc=F;fbs=64000;tlo=O;mld=0;oda=F"

Is there anything to be done here?

Comment: Please confirm if you are using 32bit drivers as suggested here https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-setup-a-connection-to-oracle-database-with-uipath/106142/10?